# How do I make the menu always visible on top?

Tags: html, css, menu

I have created the menu which works fine with all the links and responsiveness but there is some issue.
Example:
When I click on about us the menu get disappear but link is working fine the only issue is my menu disappear from the page. I want my menu to be there like fixed. Can anyone help me to figure out the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {margin:0;font-family:Arial}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #ea8537;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 17px;    
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.topnav a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child), .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown {float: none;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown-content {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About Us</a>
  <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Services
      <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="https://www.google.com">Google</a>
      <a href="https://www.gmail.com">Gmail</a>
      
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#">Disclaimer</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
  if (x.className === "topnav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    x.className = "topnav";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no problem that you describe in the code you gave. Perhaps the problem is in another part of the code.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov can you tell me where the problem is.

Comment: we will be happy to help you, but just explain the problem better. What means - "Menu disappear on clicking"?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov When I click on contact page ...it is successfully redirecting to contact page but the problem is the menu disappear.

Comment: In order to have a menu show on all pages, it needs to be either replicated on every page OR be contained in it's own file and 'included' in each page using server side code (e.g. PHP, ASP.NET).

Comment: @Micky, now I am starting to understand your problem. How do your pages load? Through ajax or not?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov No.... I have directly given a link

Comment: @Micky, If by clicking on the menu you go to a separate html page, then you need to include the markup of this menu in each page.

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov okey...I will try

Comment: @Micky, did you solve the problem?

Comment: @sergeykuznetsov not yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.navbar { /* navbar = your "topnav" */
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #333;
position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
top: 0; /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
width: 100%; /* Full width */
}
```

reference:https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp